# Drawing a straight line

Tags: tizen, tizen-native-app

On a Galaxy Watch there is an app (Samsung Health), which provides information about you.

These information are separated by a straight horizontal line, and I had no luck finding out how to draw this kind of separator. This might be my fault, but Tizen's documentation is somewhat *incomplete*.

Whenever I tried finding of how to draw a line, Google also always forwarded me to *Cairo* which I believe is not the way of doing this one:

[image]

Guys, please tell me, how the **** can I separate my data on the screen?

Comment: Could you tell us what kind of language (web, C#, C) you want to use?

Comment: If you share your codes, it will be helpful.

Comment: I'm using Native C/C++ code for development. Best way I can achieve this is drawing a RECT with 1px height but that seems odd to me.

Comment: Create ur own layout using edc. that is the best way. otherwise using evas_object_rectangle_add and give a color, size, move resize callback....
You can create an object floating in the canvas regardless of other objects.

Comment: Can you please look at my other Tizen issue with SVG: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65939893/svg-is-not-displayed-after-migrating-from-tizen4-to-tizen5-5-neither-in-emulato Sorry for asking this here, but there is no available forum where I can get in touch. JIRA is not working, facebook is handled by a bot. forum is not sending email

Answer (score 1):

In Tizen Native, there is no special function for such separator.
To implement such separator, it seems there are 2 ways as follows.

1. Using evas_object_rectangle_add() as you and [Woochan Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5977475/woochan-lee) commented

```
//Sets a rectangle into a container. (e.g. box)
//Animation and transition applied to the container is also applied to the rectangle.
//(e.g. naviframe's transition effect)
Evas_Object *naviframe = elm_naviframe_add(parent);
...
Evas_Object *box = elm_box_add(naviframe);
...

Evas_Object *rect = evas_object_rectangle_add(evas_object_evas_get(box));
evas_object_size_hint_min_set(rect, width, height);
evas_object_color_set(rect, r, g, b, a);
evas_object_show(rect);
elm_box_pack_end(box, rect);

elm_naviframe_item_push(naviframe, ..., box, ...);
```

```
//Shows a rectangle to a specific position.
//Animation and transition is not automatically applied to the rectangle.
Evas_Object *rect = evas_object_rectangle_add(evas_object_evas_get(parent));
evas_object_resize(rect, width, height);
evas_object_color_set(rect, r, g, b, a);
evas_object_move(rect, x, y);
evas_object_show(rect);
```

2. Using custom edc as [Woochan Lee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5977475/woochan-lee) commented